# Does the domain of an IntVar affect the performance of a CP-SAT solver

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

Dears,
I normally specify big IntVar even if they are not needed:

```
model.NewIntVar(-93372036854775808, 9123372036854775807, 'test')
```

Does it affect the performances of the Solver or is it irrelevant? I mean is it better to limit the domain of the variable to a reasonable one or is it not impacting the solver logics?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is better to limit the domain of the variables.

1. step away as much as possible from overflow values
2. perfectly tight domains are not mandatory, as presolve will tighten them. But some presolve rules may scan all values. So it is better to give small domains.